# librtmp , The question about the function a RTMP_SetupURL

Tags: rtmp, rtmpdump

I have a RTMP push stream address:

```
rtmp://xx.xx.xx.xx:13535/cmdlb/hq-233_cmdlb?token=6e0e607b6bb74cdbb3d8f5cb6848a6b2
```

I want to write it this way，does the token parameter take effect ?
or the parameter after '?' needs another way of writing:

```
RTMP_SetupURL(rtmpPush, "rtmp://xx.xx.xx.xx:13535/cmdlb/hq-233_cmdlb?token=6e0e607b6bb74cdbb3d8f5cb6848a6b2") ;
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been verified that it works